# Cassandra compact storage option with compound keys

Tags: cassandra, composite-key

How compact storage works in case of having a table like:

```
Table Index {
    userid
    keyword
    score
    fid
    PRIMARY KEY (userid, keyword, score)
}
```

Do not pay attention on the syntax errors of my table:)
let' assume there is one keyword containing 6 fID divided to 3 groups of different scores. How will cassandra store the data in physical layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test this, I created your sample schema (using `WITH COMPACT STORAGE`) with the above PRIMARY KEY, and ran these 6 `INSERT`s:

```
INSERT INTO dontnameyourtableindex (userid, keyword, score,fid) VALUES (3,'Star Wars',87,1);
INSERT INTO dontnameyourtableindex (userid, keyword, score,fid) VALUES (3,'Star Wars',87,2);
INSERT INTO dontnameyourtableindex (userid, keyword, score,fid) VALUES (3,'Star Wars',21,3);
INSERT INTO dontnameyourtableindex (userid, keyword, score,fid) VALUES (3,'Star Wars',21,4);
INSERT INTO dontnameyourtableindex (userid, keyword, score,fid) VALUES (3,'Star Wars',44,5);
INSERT INTO dontnameyourtableindex (userid, keyword, score,fid) VALUES (3,'Star Wars',44,6);
```

Note that due to your PRIMARY KEY definition, I ended-up with these three CQL rows:

```
 userid | keyword      | score | fid
--------+--------------+-------+-----
      3 |    Star Wars |    21 |   4
      3 |    Star Wars |    44 |   6
      3 |    Star Wars |    87 |   2

(3 rows)
```

The thing with Cassandra PRIMARY KEYs is that they are unique. So if you want to ensure uniqueness down to fID, then you should make that it is the last part of the PRIMARY KEY...PRIMARY KEY (userid, keyword, score,fID) That will ensure uniqueness, and still allow you to sort by keyword and score.

To view how these are structured at the physical level, I can use the `cassandra-cli` (instead of cqlsh):

```
[aploetz@unknown] use stackoverflow;
Authenticated to keyspace: stackoverflow
[default@stackoverflow] list dontnameyourtableindex ;
Using default limit of 100
Using default cell limit of 100
-------------------
RowKey: 3
=> (name=Star Wars:21, value=4, timestamp=1425307959946184)
=> (name=Star Wars:44, value=6, timestamp=1425307961062608)
=> (name=Star Wars:87, value=2, timestamp=1425307959909671)
```

Note that the `WITH COMPACT STORAGE` keeps the `fid` column name from appearing, and instead only shows the values with the corresponding column keys.

Comment: Great thanks for your answer, but now I am fully confused. Why you ended up with only 3 rows? Let's consider a more simple case without having the column Score. The user should keep the file identities containing the given keyword... In that case the keyword may be contained in hundreds of files. so will you again be ended-up with one CQL row??

Comment: @user3201666  Edit made.  But yes, if you removed the `score` column, then those 6 INSERTs would result in only one CQL row.  As I added above, you probably want to add `fID` as the last part of your PRIMARY KEY, to ensure uniqueness.

Comment: Thanks @BryceAtNetwork23. I need to keep many fIDs for the same user_id, keyword and score. What is the most memory efficient way to do that? Wide rows? Adding fID to composite index?? Really need to figure out this .. THe point is i also can not use Lists as the number of fID may exceed the limit 655536

Comment: @user3201666 I would go with `PRIMARY KEY (userid, keyword, score, fID)`, which will store your data in a wide-row format partitioned by `userid`.